# How to add dirty indicator( red indicator) to a field in grid after editing in ExtJS editable grid?

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1, editablegrid

How can I show the field is dirty (usually red triangle in the top left corner of the field) in an editable grid whenever that field is edited. Is there any easy technique to show it ?

Comment: It is over there by default.

Comment: It is based on the record in the store.  If the field is dirty (originalvalue != currentValue) then you get the red triangle.  if you save and commit the record then the triangle goes away.